# OpenSSL command to include "basicConstraints" extension

Tags: ssl, openssl

A certificate is generated using the following openssl command :

```
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout server.key.pem -out server.crt.pem -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf  -extensions cust_const
```

The corresponding CSR is generated using the command:

```
openssl x509 -x509toreq -in server.crt.pem -signkey server.key.pem -out server.csr -extensions cust_const
```

The conf file (openssl.cnf) has the below mentioned entry.

```
[ cust_const ]

basicConstraints       = CA:FALSE
```

The problem is that the generated CSR doesn't include `basicConstraints` extension.

How can `basicConstraints` be included into the CSR when we already have a certificate with `basicConstraints` in it?

Comment: `x509 -x509toreq` uses `X509_to_X509_REQ` a very basic routine that sets only version, subject, and pubkeyinfo. Why are you generating a dummy cert *then* a CSR? If you want to use the dummy cert you don't need the CSR and if you want to use the CSR to get a (maybe real) cert you don't need the dummy cert. `req -new` *without* `-x509` can generate a CSR containing extensions (`-reqexts` on commandline or `req_extensions` in configfile) -- although CAs generally won't put extensions from the CSR in the cert.

Comment: In our implementation we want to generate the cert first and then the CSR. The "basicConstraints" extension is included in the cert while it is not present in the CSR. Is there a way to get that extension in the CSR from the cert?

Comment: You 'want to' do this, but give no reason why, and I can't see any reason that would make it useful. If you insist on doing something useless, you can generate the CSR with the same data you put in the cert (but not actually taken from the cert), or if you insist on actually taking it from the cert you'll have to write a program to do it: all the needed `PEM_*` routines and some `X509_*` and `X509_REQ_*` have man pages; the missing ones generally follow the same pattern and all have C-level details in the `.h` files.

Answer (score 1):

when you want to create a CSR to be signed by other `CA` he will "make" you CA as well ( e.g. root will sign intermediate as CA with depthLen=1 , where intermediate will sign endPoint as CA=FALSE ... )

first you need to understand what do you want to do (root / intermediate / Endpoint)

if you are root create extensions file (look for openssl default for help...)

below short list command to help you get started :

```
create root ca certificate
    openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootca.key 2048
    openssl rsa -in rootca.key -out rootca.key.insecure
    openssl req -key rootca.key.insecure -new -x509 -days 3650 -extensions v3_ca -out rootca.crt
    openssl x509 -text -in rootca.crt
    NOTE:
        it uses the default extensions file: /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf (or /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf)
create intermediate certificate
    openssl genrsa -des3 -out intermediate.key 2048
    openssl rsa -in intermediate.key -out intermediate.key.insecure
    openssl req -new -key intermediate.key.insecure -out intermediate.csr
        NOTE: you might need these commands before the next command 'openssl ca'.
            mkdir demoCA
            touch demoCA/index.txt
            echo 1122334455667788 > demoCA/serial
    openssl ca -extensions v3_ca -days 3650 -outdir . -batch -cert rootca.crt -keyfile rootca.key.insecure -in intermediate.csr -out intermediate.crt
        NOTE: after run 'openssl ca' you can remove the demoCA folder
            rm -rf demoCA
    openssl x509 -text -in intermediate.crt
    openssl verify -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt
create server/client certificate
    openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
    openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key.insecure
    openssl req -new -key server.key.insecure -out server.csr
    openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -CAcreateserial -CA intermediate.crt -CAkey intermediate.key.insecure -in server.csr -out server.crt
    openssl x509 -text -in server.crt
```